# SSRS BIDS How to change "Deploy" account credentials

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I'm using BIDS (Visual Studio 2008) to create and deploy SSRS reports to a report server, on a third-party hosted server.

The username and password that it uses to deploy reports onto the report server seems to be saved somehow, and I don't seem to be able to change it. Is there a way of changing this account? I'm getting a rsAccessDenied as expected. Previously it has asked for a username and password. To confirm, I'm getting this in the Error List pane:

```
The permissions granted to user 'SERVERNAME\ssrs' are
insufficient for performing this operation.
```

I can't start the software using these credentials as they only exist on the server. I can't change the permissions of this "fixed" account either as it's used by staff for read-only viewing of the reports. I already have an account for writing to the server that I would use if this software would let me.

I've looked at every setting I could find and I've tried creating a new solution, copying the report I need to deploy to this solution, but it still doesn't ask me for credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The credentials were saved in Windows Control Panel -> Credential Manager (I'm on Windows 7). Just edit or delete the "Windows Credentials" for the server. For me, these credentials were, I think, saved by Internet Explorer rather than BIDS, but BIDS is happy to use them anyway.